# response.data.key return undefined when i want to grab or get some specific fields from Json data or API with axios.get

Tags: javascript, axios

when I send a get request to the following endpoint 
https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/ it returns the JSON data like below...

```
{
        "name": "Andorra",
        "native": "Andorra",
        "phone": "376",
        "continent": "EU",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "languages": [
            "ca"
        ],
        "emoji": "",
        "emojiU": "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9",
        "code": "AD"
    },
```

it returns all the available countries that were stored in the JSON data. And it shows all the fields like name, native and so on. But I want to show some specific field like continent and language, not all the fields in the lists.I am trying like

```
response.data.continent
```

but it returns undefined. My get request is

```
 axios.get(`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/`)
```

It shows correct data if I filter with a single country but I want to show some field for all the countries that were on the list.

Comment: `https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/` returns an ARRAY of objects like the one you posted ... so it's `response.data[n].continent` where n is 0 to 249 (because there are 250 of those objects in the response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/` returns an ARRAY of objects like the one you posted ... so it's `response.data[n].continent` where n is 0 to 249 (because there are 250 of those objects in the response)

here's an example using javascript fetch instead of axios, but the principal is the same

```js
fetch('https://countriesnode.herokuapp.com/v1/countries/')
.then(r => r.json())
.then(data => data.map(({name, continent, languages}) => ({name, continent, languages})))
.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But i am trying to change or insert the data inside the html like this

resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(result);

But it didn't work and shows undefined. But the result is correct in the console. Any suggestion ???

Comment: @bappi - none of what you just said in that comment is at all described in your question. How would I possibly know what you want to do with the data once you have it?